# Call file in powershell script using relative and absolute path

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powershell-v5.1

My script runs from
C:\ABC\DEF\Tools\Powershell\Development>myscript.ps1

I want to use this file in myscript.ps1 from this Relative path  location
'.\AOI\UDT\testfile.text'

I cannot use absolute path 'C:\ABC\DEF\AOI\UDT\testfile.text' because it will be running in different machine later.

```
<# Import Script for testing>  
<. $PSScriptRoot\myscript.ps1>  
<$filpath = '.\AOI\UDT\testfile.text'>
<$Routine = Get-Content -path $filpath -ErrorAction Stop>
```

Error I get
Cannot find  path 'C:\ABC\DEF\Tools\Powershell\Development\AOI\UDT\testfile.text' because it does not exist

I am new to programming. Can anyone help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Can you include the content of your script (or part of it having this problem) into the question?

Comment: # Import Script for testing          
. $PSScriptRoot\myscript.ps1      
$filpath = '.\AOI\UDT\testfile.text'      
$Routine = Get-Content -path $filpath -ErrorAction Stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$filepath = (Resolve-Path ($PSScriptRoot + "\..\..\..\AOI\UDT\testfile.text"))
```

This worked best for me.

Answer (score 0):

Relative to the directory you are executing the script in, the path to your testfile.text would be:

```
$filepath = "..\..\..\AOI\UDT\testfile.text"
```